# Is it possible to make the ORDER BY clause a NO-OP without excluding it entirely?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In SQL if you specify, say, `LIMIT ALL` or `OFFSET 0`, the query behaves as if you didn't include the clauses at all. A no-op if you will.

Is it possible to do this with the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: `order by null` ?  Is that what you mean.

Comment: That sounds right, yes! (I was thinking `order by none` or something, but I hadn't seen it in any documentation)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work though. `ERROR: non-integer constant in ORDER BY`

Comment: NO-OP result wise? I guess, otherwise one should check EXPLAIN et al. for impact on query planning / execution differences with vs. without. In simple cases by rowid or whatever is the stable insert order handle in postgresql might work, but in a general case I would be surprised - never the less  curious to learn ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any expression that's not a simple constant will work, eg:

```
order by (false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
order by (select 1)
```

or:

```
order by (select null::text)
```

However, I'm not sure that these are "no-ops".  They may still do the sort, re-arranging the data.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more ideas, arguably simpler:

```
ORDER BY 1+0
```

or

```
ORDER BY ARRAY[1]
```